# C# List Error, I try to search an item from the list in another class but show nothing exists

Tags: c#

I created the list to Products and my objective is to search them in another class to can add them to a datagridview. But when i search the program dont find the number of Reference(Referencia). 
How i solve this problem?

**SEARCH.cs**

```
    bool encontrou = false;
        this.dataGridViewAdicionarProduto.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (Produto prod in Program.listaProdutos)
        {
            if (prod.refProduto == Convert.ToInt16(this.txtProcurar.Text))
            {
                this.dataGridViewAdicionarProduto.Rows.Add(prod.refProduto, prod.nome, prod.quantidade, prod.preco);
                encontrou = true;
            }
        }
        if (encontrou == false)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Não foi encontrada nenhuma referencia", "Procurar Referencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.txtProcurar.ResetText();
            this.txtProcurar.Focus();
        }
```

**ProductCreate.cs:**

```
  Produto prod;
    private void btnCriar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prod = new Produto(Convert.ToInt16(this.txtReferencia.Text),this.txtNomeProduto.Text, Convert.ToInt16(this.txtQuantidadeProdut.Text), Convert.ToDouble(this.txtPrecoProduto.Text));

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtReferencia.Text,txtNomeProduto.Text, txtQuantidadeProdut.Text, txtPrecoProduto.Text);

        Program.listaProdutos.Add(prod); 

    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
  static class Program
      {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new CriarClientes());       
    }

    public static List<Produto> listaProdutos =new List<Produto>();
    public static  List<Cliente> cliente = new List<Cliente>();
}
```

Comment: Everytime you call Program.listaProdutos you get a new list, this will always be empty.

Comment: There is a term called 'debugging'. It's sometimes good to do that.